# Using DELETE with a WITH-Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

As a SQL-beginner I encountered the following SQL-statement:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT T0, row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY T0 ORDER BY Datum desc, ID desc) AS [rn]
  FROM [Data].[dbo].[tab_MATERIAL]
)
DELETE cte WHERE [rn] > 1
```

I know that it is supposed to delete dublicates. Does it? 
I know cte is a view-like thing. If I "delete cte", does this actually impact the original table? And if it does, does it actually delete exactly the rows specified? Or does it delete the entries with T0 occuring with rn>1 in cte?

Where would I be able to find this kind of information online?

Comment: You are not deleting `cte`, you are instead deleting rows in a table using a `cte`, you are deleting any rows  rn>1 from the actual table

Comment: Yes to all. You can use `DELETE` with views too. The rough rule for updatable views and CTEs is that individual rows have to be identifiable. You can't update a CTE or view that returns aggregated results for example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this affects the original table.  This is called an *updatable CTE* in SQL Server.  You can also include the code as a subquery or in a view, and it will still delete from the original table.

I think there is a misnomer because people often confuse CTEs with temporary tables.  They are not the same thing.  Although a CTE can be materialized in a query (although not in SQL Server typically), there is no logical "temporary table" involved.

If you attempt something like an aggregation in the subquery, you will get an error that the CTE is not updatable.